# 3rd Principal Part of *refero*

Tags: verbs, irregular-words, compound-verb

The Latin word for "report" is *refero, referre, rettuli, relatus*. At first, I thought that *rettuli*, with 2 t's, was a typo, but it actually appears that *retuli*, with just 1 t, is the uncommon form in comparison.
This seems rather strange to me, because most of the compounds of *fero* do not seem to double the t. For example:

> *defero, deferre, detuli, delatus*
>   *effero, efferre, extuli, elatus*
>   *offero, offerre, obtuli, oblatus*
>   *infero, inferre, intuli, illatus*

Why is *refero* an exception? Additionally, what instances are there of Latin writers using the more uncommon form of *retuli* instead of *rettuli*?

Comment: As far as I know, it doesn't come from *tuli* but from *re(d)-*. Compare with *redire*. I hope someone can give more detail and explain why the D was lost in the other forms.

Comment: Sihler's _New comparative grammar of Greek and Latin_ (§523) suggests that it's actually because of the loss of vowel from what was originally a reduplicated perfect form (*retetuli > rettuli; cf. *repeperi > repperi).

Comment: *Red-* assimilated in some other verbs as well; compare *relligio*, *reccido*. Don't know why this happened only sometimes though.

Comment: Cf. *reddo*. <filler text>

Comment: related http://latin.stackexchange.com/a/618/39

Answer (score 6):

As @cnread's comment indicates, the geminate *t* of *rettuli* is thought to be a remnant of Indo-European perfect reduplication.

The Proto-Indo-European perfect tense was formed with reduplication of the first consonant of the root; a few Latin perfects still do this, e.g. *cecidi, peperi, cucurri*. *Rettuli* would then come from an older form *re-tetuli*; the short *e*, which would have been unaccented in early Latin (in which accent was on the initial syllable), was lost by syncope and the two *t*'s fell together. The same explanation accounts for other such forms, e.g. *reccidi, repperi*. (The geminate *d* of the present *reddo* is probably due to the same phenomenon, except that in this case the reduplication was a present-stem formant rather than a perfect marker, cf. Greek δί-δωμι.)

Comment: This makes sense, but why does it only happen in the prefixed form? We don't see *_tutulī_, for example, even though the initial stress would have preserved the first vowel.

Comment: @Draconis, that's quite true -- most perfects that were reduplicated in PIE lost their reduplication in Latin. I don't know of any good explanation for why the handful of verbs that retained it did so (which is often the case with morphological change).

Comment: Interesting answer. There are a few things I still don't understand: 1. why no *dettuli, praettuli, prottuli*? Does it have something to do with vowel length? 2. Why do you think *reddo* is reduplication, too, rather than the *-d* that is often part of the prefix *re(d)-*?

Comment: The Latin perfect continues both the IE perfect and the IE aorist. That is why it has lots of different forms.

Comment: @Cerberus, 1 is hard to answer because (so to speak) regularization is irregular -- in the course of language change some forms get regularized and others don't; that said, it's possible vowel length was relevant -- Latin does have something of an aversion to superlong syllables (long vowel + coda consonant), though not an absolute one. (Note that the *red-* account runs into the same problem -- why *red-* in this form but *re-* normally?) 2. This verb shows reduplication in the present in other IE languages; and *red-* is a prevocalic alternant of *re-*, like *prod-* for *pro-*.

Answer (score 3):

The prefix *re-* also appears as *red-*, an older form which mostly disappeared along with other final *-d*s (personal *med*, preposition *extrad*, imperative *estod*, ablative *marid*...). You can see this *d* in forms like *red-īre* and *red-dere*, and remnants of it in *religiō/relligiō* and *redūcō/rēdūcō* (assimilation and compensatory lengthening).

While most *-d*s disappeared, some words (like your *rettulī*) kept their older forms...sometimes. As L&S put it, ["[t]he orthography and quantity of words compounded with *re* are in general somewhat arbitrary, especially in the ante- and post-class[ical] poets"](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aalphabetic%20letter%3DR%3Aentry%20group%3D4%3Aentry%3Dre1). So while *rettulī* was the most common form, [*retulī* and *rētulī* were by no means unheard of](http://latin.packhum.org/concordance?q=retul) especially in Pliny, and Lucretius also used forms like *rellatus*/*rēlatus* (showing the *-d* in the fourth stem).

Comment: AFAIK, *red-* is only prevocalic; *rettuli, reccidi, reddo* all reflect original reduplicated forms with vowel loss. Not sure about *relligio*, but it was explained as metrical lengthening already in antiquity (see Servius Honoratus quote [here](http://latin.packhum.org/search?q=relligi)). De Vaan thinks the *d* of *red-* is not inherited but secondary, based on an analogy like *pro(d)*-. For *rellatus/rēlatus*, I suppose they may be etymologically explicable, from *re-tlatus*

Answer (score 2):

A brief comment re: geminate vs. non-geminate perfect forms of refero.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Where are you getting this data from? You probably have access to more sophisticated tools, but a naive corpus search shows 628 hits for #rettul and 148 hits for #retul, which is certainly less conclusive than this chart.

Comment: @brianpck the corpus is called Opera Latina (University of Liege), http://web.philo.ulg.ac.be/lasla/ It lets you search for specific morphological forms, so I got data for perfectum only.

Comment: The discrepancy between these numbers and those from PHI (@brianpck) is strange -- I wonder what accounts for it.

Comment: @TKR I just searched another POS tagged corpus (LatinISE historical corpus v2), and I got this: Query rettuli.*, Romana Antiqua, Romana Classica  163 (12.54 per million); Query retuli.*, Romana Antiqua, Romana Classica  12 (0.92 per million).

Comment: @brianpck I just looked more closely at your data. 47 occurrences of retul# (out of 148) come from the 4-5 century AD grammarian Maurus Servius Honoratus.

Comment: @AlexB. I saw a few discrepancies like that, but (if I'm not mistaken) there were almost 10 just from Livy, which by itself is more than what is included in this chart.