# What would the perfect stem of 'apparere' be?

Tags: verbs, morphology, prefix, perfect-tense, reduplicatio

[Lewis and Short](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dappario) only give present stem forms of the verb *appărĕre*, *appărio*.
They say, quite rightly so, that it comes from *ad+părĕre*, and one would therefore expect the conjugation to be as that for *părĕre*.
I interpret the lack of perfect forms in the dictionary entry to indicate that those forms are not attested, not that they are illegal in any sense.
If I want to use the perfect forms of this verb, how should I go about it?

The conjugation of *parere* is *pario, peperi, partus/paritus*.
Therefore one natural guess is *appario, appeperi, appartus/apparitus*.
However, it is not unusual for reduplication to be lost after a prefix, as in *cucurri > concurri*.
Therefore also *appario, apperi, appartus/apparitus* would make sense.
Which one should I pick, ***appeperi* or *apperi*, or something else**?
Or are both fine?

If there is a general rule that allows to decide whether reduplication is retained with prefixes, that would certainly settle this question.
If no such thing exists in the literature, then one can only presumably argue by analogy to examples.

The verb in question is not to be confused with *appārēre*, from which we derive e.g. *appāritio*.
I am not aware of any such derivatives of *appărĕre*.
There are three verbs *pario* in Latin, but they are distinguished by their infinitives: [*pariare*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=pario1&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059), [*parere*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aalphabetic+letter%3DP%3Aentry+group%3D13%3Aentry%3Dpario2), and [*parire*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aalphabetic+letter%3DP%3Aentry+group%3D13%3Aentry%3Dpario3).
The verb of this question is of the third conjugation, but it is somewhat confusing that there are so similar-looking verbs in all other conjugations.

Comment: Perhaps apperi? You may want to take a look at https://latin.stackexchange.com/a/618/39

Comment: Another compound verb derived from *pario* is *reperio*, with an attested perfect *repperi*. I guess the geminated *-p-* is the result of a collapsed reduplication?

Comment: @Cairnarvon That sounds like an excellent argument. Do you want to write a suggestion based on that as an answer? The general observations pointed out by Alex seem to support it.

Comment: @Batavulus I added some extra clarification to my last paragraph. Notice that I always referred to the verb as *părĕre*, so *parire* is out of the question. [I converted your answer to a comment as there were flags about it. Asking for clarification should go into a comment.]